# New Build Cursor Off Set

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, system

Our team has built a unity application and when we built the current build, the mouse cursor was off set on some of our window computers. For example, we have one scene which is a login screen. When the user goes to select the submit button, you have to hit above to the left of the button.

We haven't made any changes to the cursor via scripts and on some computers it works. For my mac build, we had no problems.

The computer with the problem is Window 7 and has all the system requirements.

Comment: What about the resolution, is it different across devices?

Comment: We set the application to have a set resolution and they can open to full screen if they want.